# How do I use mutagens?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've collected a nice selection of mutagens so far, but I have no idea on how to actually use them. They are supposed to be able to improve my character somehow.

How exactly do I apply those mutagens?

[image]

Comment: Ah, nothing breaks the immersion better than seeing a double helix in a fantasy game.

Comment: @Oak Bioshock isn't a fantasy game?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mutagens boost your abilities which allow a mutagen slot.

You can loot one from a defeated enemy or you can create one as a byproduct of alchemy.

To apply a mutagen, go into quick menu and choose meditation (Default key: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>), then select the **Character** option and find an ability 
that has a mutagen slot ([list of abilities with mutagen slots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/which-abilities-contain-mutagen-slots/22680#22680)). Select the ability, and choose Mutate (<kbd>Enter</kbd>). Select the desired mutagen from the list and choose Mutate Ability (<kbd>Space</kbd>).

The mutation cannot be reversed.

Mutagens usually take one of three forms: *lesser*, *basic* and *greater*. Each of these forms raises the character’s statistics, but by a different amount:

- **Critical effects mutagen**: Increases the chance of causing critical effect.
- **Range mutagen**: Increases the range of the Aard, Igni and Axii Signs.
- **Vitality mutag**: Increases vitality.
- **Power mutagen**: Increases sword damage.
- **Strength mutagen**: Increases damage reduction.
- **Concentration mutagen**: Increases Sign damage.
- **Madness mutagen**: +2 armor, +5 vitality
- **Enhancement mutagen**: Increases adrenaline generation on hitting foe

Comment: There are even more mutagens than these listed in the manual, at least I found some that aren't listed here.

Comment: That is cool. The Wikia page is not up2date with TW2 info yet, so maybe you should initiate? :)

Comment: We could just update your answer here with mutagens we find. I'd probably need to update my question to also ask about what the mutagens do.

Comment: That's a good idea. Are you sure the mutagens you found are not sub-classes of the above mentioned?

Comment: I've found just the one unusal one so far, I've edited it into the answer

Comment: @Tergiver what is this Enhancement mutagen you added?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use them in combination with certain abilities in your skill tree - e.g. if you activate "fortitude" in the basic branch, a small circle allows you to use a mutagen of similar effect. Definitely something that should have been explained in more detail.

Comment: Is there any information on how many slots there are? It also seems that one should only use the Greater mutagens if the number of slots is limited.